# Ubuntu 17.04 is too slow after install . But is normal on live usb

Tags: kubuntu

Ubuntu 17.04 is slow after install and xorg use almost whole cpu when watch `top` command result in terminal.

I tried installing nvidia graphic  driver  but it created a login loop and after restart cant login to Ubuntu so must purge nvidia for login successfully.

Any idea how  to solve it?
Im using  msi pe60-6qe notebook  and this is a dual boot installation with windows 10.

Comment: I suggest that you try the still developing version 'Artful' to be released as 17.10 during this month (October 2017). http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/383/builds ; It has a new kernel with new drivers, which might work better with your graphics card. (I think you need a proprietary nvidia graphic driver to get good performance, but also the new nouveau driver might be better than the old one for your computer.) -- Have you tried with the boot option `nomodeset`, which might help during the early stages (to avoid a login loop)?

Comment: actually it was `nomodeset` problem . i removed it from grub and every thing is fine .thanks to  mention that .